# Does the law of excluded middle hold in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, decidability

In propositional logic, we create well-formed formulas out of logical connective symbols and propositional variables. Then we can consider a valuation function that first assigns a true/false value to each propositional variable, and then assigns a true/false value to every well-formed formula by certain rules. If I'm not mistaken, all well-formed formulas of the form
$$ \varphi \vee \neg\varphi $$
(where $\varphi$ is a well-formed formula) are true for all possible valuations, so they are tautologies. Thus, we can conclude that the law of excluded middle holds for propositional logic.

Now in first-order logic, I know that we need to assign an interpretation or structure to our language, and then [based on certain rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_structures) we assign true/false values to the relevant well-formed formulas that are propositions.

**Question:** In FOL, does every wff of the form $\varphi \vee \neg\varphi$ (where $\varphi$ is a wff) always evaluate to being true? Truth assignment in first-order logic seems so different than in propositional logic that I am not able to reason through such a simple question.

Comment: Yes. If there aren’t any quantifiers then first-order logic reduces to propositional logic.

Comment: It holds even when $\varphi$ is a formula with quantifiers.  The easiest way to see that this must be true is the Completeness Theorem.  There can be no model in which neither $\varphi$ nor $\lnot \varphi$ holds.

Comment: @RobertShore This is not a valid argument. The fact that there can be no model in which neither $\phi$ nor $\neg \phi$ holds only shows that $\models \neg (\neg \phi \land \neg \neg \phi)$, but it does not show $\models \phi \lor \neg \phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Every formula that is a first-order *instance* of a propositional tautology, i.e. one that can one get by substituting first-order formulas for propositional letters in a propositionally valid formula, is also valid in FOL.

Comment: Ok, I want to clarify a few things with some questions. So your answer holds even if $\varphi$ from $\varphi \vee \neg\varphi$ has quantifiers in it? And the way you prove this is essentially identical to the proof in propositional logic by treating all atomic formulas as propositional variables? Am I correct in these assertions?

Comment: Yes. Provided that it really is the same $\varphi$ left and right. E.g. $\forall x \exists y P(x,y) \lor \neg \forall x \exists y P(x,y)$. And as a proof you would typically say that it's valid because it's an instance of a propositional tautology, which can then be proved by means of your choice. If you write a proof arguing about valuations/interpretations, it will be sufficient to look at the truth functions of the connectives without looking into the predicates and quantifiers.